# Discord.py - Identifying if a user id mentioned is one specific user id, then sending a message if it is

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I've been working on a bot for a couple days now that sends the current time in Athens if you mention a certain user. Got most of it up no problem, but I've been having a lot of trouble with having the bot respond to this specific user being mentioned. As of right now I'm trying to have the bot detect a mention with message.mentions and then respond if it's the correct user id.

Here's the snippet I'm having trouble with:

```py
if message.mentions:
      member = message.mentions[0]
      command, member = message.split()
      member_id = int(member.strip('<@!>'))
      member = await bot.fetch_member(member_id)
      if member == peter:
        clock = get_time()
        clock = json.dumps(clock, indent=4)
        await message.channel.send("The time in Athens is currently: ")
        await message.channel.send(clock[-11: -6])
```

And here's the full code:

```py
import os
import discord
import requests
import json
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '$')
peter = 'USERID'


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
      #For console testing purposes

def get_time():
  response = requests.get("http://api.timezonedb.com/v2.1/get-time-zone?key=W9BJQ3QMGG69&format=json&by=position&lat=37.9838&lng=23.7275")
  return response.json()
    #A function that pulls raw the appropriate timezone data from timezonedb and converts it to json

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
      return
        #Making sure it doesn't respond to itself

    if "@here" in message.content: 
      return
    if "@everyone" in message.content:
      return
        #Making sure it doesn't respond to tags including everyone

    if message.mentions:
      member = message.mentions[0]
      command, member = message.split()
      member_id = int(member.strip('<@!>'))
      member = await bot.fetch_member(member_id)
      if member == peter:
        clock = get_time()
        clock = json.dumps(clock, indent=4)
        await message.channel.send("The time in Athens is currently: ")
        await message.channel.send(clock[-11: -6])

    else:
      pass

client.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])
```

Thank you for having a look

Comment: I just need to get what do you want to do, when some specific user is mentioned you want to spend the time in a certain time zone?

Comment: Yeah basically. When one specific user is mentioned I want the bot to say the time zone in Athens. Already have the timezone bit fleshed out it's just the mentioning that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

if the mentioning is the problem here is the code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message:discord.Message):
    if message.mentions:
        if message.mentions[0].id == "insert id": 
            # do what you want
```

that should be it to read more [click here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message)